# print variable value in email body in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to print value in a date variable in my body of the email. its not working. it displays date literal on the email.

dict = {a:10, b:20, c:30}
date = "2023-09-13"

```
def send_email(dict, date):
  domain = 'smtp.abc.net'
  port = 25
  msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
  subject = "test email"  
  sender = "abc" + '@abc.net'
  receivers = ["bcd@bcd.net"]
  html = """\
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <p>NOTE: Test Email</p>
  <br>
            {}
  {{date}}
  </body>
  </html>
        """.format(dict)    
  msg = MIMEText(html, "HTML")
  msg['Subject'] = subject
  msg['From'] = sender
  msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(receivers)
  with smtplib.SMTP(domain, port) as server:
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
```

expecting "2023-09-13" instead of date